# adding functions to modular routes in mongoose/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have achieved the Wall o' Code in my server.js, and it's time to start breaking routes into their own files. I'm still figuring my way through the various answers here about how to do that, but then I came up with a related question. I think this is callback hell, or maybe it's just nested hell, but I'd like to weasel out of it, if that's possible.

For instance, when you add a Person to the db, you can link that Person to any other Person in the db, or add them via that link. That means my steps in 'save a Person' are:

1. save the Person data
2. pull out var for other-Person
3. if var not exist, skip to end
4. if var exists, search for any Person with that id/name
5. if Person found, add the Person from step #1 into other-Person data
6. if Person not found, create new-Person using name in step #2

That's a lot of nesting. I've got other similar multi-step routes going on, especially for deletion: deleting an Entry = deleting anything in Events with the Entry's ref id. Deleting a Person = looping through all Change-History objects in the Event collection to find any related to that Person. (This makes so much more sense and seems a lot less complicated when I don't say it out loud.)

So my question is: if I'm embedding routes to make my server.js file less small, is there a way to call out these repeating steps, instead of always spelling things out? Frex, if I could take something like:

```
        Event
        .find({
            'change.person_id': req.params.person_id,
            user_id: req.params.user_id
        })
        .select({
            entry: 1,
            date: 1,
            title: 1,
            order: 1,
            change: 1
        })
        .exec(function(err, events)
```

and make it into its own little function, so I can just encapsulate that action in the router.route file as something like:

```
        .get(function(req, res) {
                fetchEvents(userId, personId);
                if (err) {
                    return res.json(err);
                } else {
                    res.send(events);
                }
        });
```

Is that possible?

And equally important, are there any maintenance or performance issues that would make this a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

The quick way to making more composable async calls is to use Promises. The Mongo javascript drivers return a promise if you don't provide a call back so that's a way to start, but I have found that the Promises don't use the syntax I am used to (i.e. they seem to lack catch statements).

So an alternative is to use Bluebird and promisify your functions, and you could perhaps end up with.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var mongoConnect = Promise.promisify(mongoClient.connect);
var db;

...(req, res) => {
  mongoConnect(uri)
  .then( _db => {
    db = _db;
    // 1st async operation
  })
  .then( res => {
     // second async ....
  })
  .then( result => {
    // close connection
    db.close();
    res.send(result)
  })
  .catch( err => {
    if (db.close)
        db.close();
    return res.status(5000.send(err);
  });
}
```

Comment: That looks promising (so to speak), but Bluebird's own docs are frighteningly empty. Not even a beginner's guide. :(

Comment: Yeah, but this is only focused on promises, and nothing about whether it's actually a good idea to break the code out to this fine degree, in terms of maintenance or performance. And since I don't know whether the syntax you're using (that pushed you to use Bluebird instead) matches what I'm using, I can't even judge whether Bluebird is a good option, or just another layer of code. I mean, if I'm using syntax that meshes with Mongo's promises, why add another library on top?